# scatter plot pandas one variable on x axis and y axis is dataframe index

Tags: pandas, scatter-plot

I want to make a scatter plot in pandas the x axis is the mean  and the y axis should be the index of data frame , but I couldn't proceed this is my code I got a lot of errors .

```
y=list(range(len(df.index)))    
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='meandf', y  )    
error : SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

Comment: The error is essentially saying it doesn't know what to do with the variable `y` after you've used keyword args. Try the following: `df.plot(kind='scatter', x='meandf', y=y )`

Comment: Thanks , Now I got another error :IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds

Comment: I've added an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
y=list(range(len(df.index)))

df.meandf.plot(x='meandf', y=y)
```

Or more concisely since you're plotting a `Series`:

```
df.meandf.plot(y=y)
```

If you need to maintain `kind = 'scatter'` you'll need to pass a dataframe:

```
df['y'] = y # create y column for the list you created
df.plot(x='a', y='y', kind='scatter', marker='.')
df.drop('y', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working well, another question if I want to have a dot for each point, I have to put kind=' ' ?

Comment: @sunny Also added note realizing you were intentionally using `kind='scatter'`. See edits now.

Comment: Thanks ! It's very well.